# Why didn’t Frank just let Donnie die at 0:00

Tags: donnie-darko

In Donnie Darko, Frank is a manipulated dead there to guide to Donnie to his ultimate purpose.

Since Frank is the manipulated dead, why wouldn’t he just let Donnie stay in bed that night? Wouldn’t that align the correct timeline anyway? Then Donnie wouldn’t have to sacrifice himself, or is this more about choice (Donnies)?

Comment: Manipulated dead?

Comment: @morbo "Manipulated dead" is a term generally used/known by those who are into figuring out the meaning behind Donnie Darko. I don't fully understand it myself, but I know I've seen it used in several different "Donnie Darko Explanation" sites and videos.

Comment: There are alot of donnie darko questions...i’d suggest resding through the tags

Comment: There's a feature on the DVD release of the movie that is basically a copy of the book that the old lady gave Donnie in the movie.  You can read through her knowledge of time travel.  It also defines terms like "manipulated dead" and explains a fair bit about what was going on in the movie.  I don't know if there's an online source these days, but if there is, linking it in the question would probably help answerers to formulate... answers. ;)